# respond.js with bootstrap 3 and IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, respond-to

In **Inernet Explorer 8** Can someone please tell me why the column width on the [services page](http://virtonei.co.uk/services) are shorter than what they should be? They should be similiar to the yellow highlighted area below:

[image: services page on website]

I tried viewing it in Browser Stack and using Emulation Mode from within IE11. I am using **respond.js** like described in [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems in IE8:

**First problem:**

```
<dt>
    <i class="icon-data-consolidation"></i>
</dt>
```

This `<dt>` tag has a diferent size on IE8 than any other browser. (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc). For example in Mozilla it has `width = 45px ; height = 45px` and in IE8 it has `width = 160px ; height = 45px;`. So because of this 160px width of the `<dt>` tags that you have in the page, your design crashes.

**Solution for first problem:**

Add this into your css code:

```
.dl-horizontal dt {
    width: 45px !important;
}
```

**Second problem:**

```
<dd>
    <h5>Data Consolidation</h5>
    <p>Data from disparate systems ...</p>
</dd>
```

This `<dd>` tag has a margin-left = 45px in Firefox, but in IE8 it's set to 180px.

**Solution for the second problem:**

Add this into your css code:

```
.dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 45px !important;
}
```

I've tested this and it works, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me **where the different width comes from?** In my stylesheet I did have the correct widths without the override `important`

Comment: To be honest, i don't know exactly. IE8 is hard to debug, i only noticed the diference and i saw that adding this lines will make your design look good. I did that using IE8 developer tools.